# Bash Script To Remove RAW Files Which Don't Have A Corresponding JPEG File

Tags: bash

I'd shoot my camera in RAW/JPEG mode, and since the RAW images are huge (in file size), it takes forever to preview them so I preview the JPEGs, and delete those which I don't want.

For instance, if I have:

```
image1.CR2
image1.jpg
image2.CR2
image2.jpg
image3.CR2
image4.CR2
image5.CR2
...
```

I'd like to delete the `.CR2` which don't have a matching `.jpg` (images 3 through 5 in this example).

I came across the following code:

```
rm *.CR2(e:'[[ ! -e ${REPLY%.CR2}.jpg ]]':)
```

but it doesn't work on my machine.  I've not touched Bash in donkey's years so I'm at a loss at trying to resolve it.

I get the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: That command is for `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: That'll be why it doesn't work!  Thanks Yurij :)

Comment: @DaveMelia what do you mean? :)

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I mean, if it's for zsh and not bash (like you said)... That's why it doesn't work for me (Because I'm running it in bash)

Comment: Comment about zsh was from @Kevin :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
for x in *.CR2
do
    [ -e "${x%.CR2}.jpg" ] || echo rm "$x"
done
```

This looks at every `.CR2` file and calls it `x`. [`${x%.CR2}` expands to the filename with `.CR2` removed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), so we add the `.jpg` extension on and check whether that exists [with `-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). If it doesn't, we remove the original `.CR2` file.

The above has an extra `echo` in it so you can check it's picking the files you want before you actually delete anything. You can put it all on one line if you want:

```
for x in *.CR2 ; do [ -e "${x%.CR2}.jpg" ] || echo rm "$x"; done
```

and it'll be easy to edit interactively.

Some shells have more powerful parameter expansion that might be able to do this, but Bash isn't one of them. I suspect the code you found was targeting one of those.

Comment: gold answer! thanks!